# Simple number theory

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I'm new in number theory and I was asked this question:
For the number $N$ output the amount of numbers $M$, such that $1 \le M \le N$, $\gcd(M, N) \ne 1$ and $\gcd(M, N) \ne M$.
How can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**

- For a given integer $n$ the number of integers $m$ such that $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and $1\leq m\leq n$ is exactly $\varphi(n)$
- The number of integers $m$ such that $\gcd(m,n)=m\neq 1$ and $1\leq m\leq n$  is exactly $d(n)-1$ (don't count $m=1$).
- The number of all integers $m$ such that $1\leq m\leq n$ is $n$
- Conclude that the number of integers $1\leq m\leq n$,$\gcd(m,n)\neq1$ and $\gcd(m,n)\neq m$ is :
  $$n+1-d(n)-\varphi(n) $$

Comment: But $GCD(M,N) ≠ M $, not $N$!